# impdp failing with ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, impdp

I'm trying to import a dmp file provided by our dba to my dev database. I've been able to export the contents to a `SQLFILE` and the contents look ok. I tried importing the schema and it kept on failing (same errors as shown below); so I tried running the SQL directly from the sqlfile - this created all the schema objects but didn't import the data.

The export was from the `expenses` schema from our test database. I already have another schema by that name in my dev database that I don't want to touch; so I'm remapping `expenses` to `expenses1`.

This schema (`expenses1`) has READ and WRITE privilege on the data_pump_dir directory. It has, as far as I can tell, all the privileges it needs (create table, view, procedure, sequence, etc) as well as IMP_FULL_DATABASE.

```
[oradev@DIAS45 dpdump]$ impdp expenses1/expenses1 logfile=expenses1.log
  remap_schema=EXPENSES:EXPENSES1 directory=data_pump_dir
  dumpfile=ossarct_expenses_expdp.dmp
  content=DATA_ONLY schemas=EXPENSES include=TABLE

Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Apr 16 09:28:21 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

UDI-31626: operation generated ORACLE error 31626
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-39086: cannot retrieve job information
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3326
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4551
ORA-06512: at line 1

[oradev@DIAS45 dpdump]$ cat expenses1.log
;;;
Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Apr 16 09:28:21 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;;
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Master table "EXPENSES1"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "EXPENSES1"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01":  expenses1/******** logfile=expenses1.log
  remap_schema=EXPENSES:EXPENSES1 directory=data_pump_dir
  dumpfile=ossarct_expenses_expdp.dmp content=DATA_ONLY schemas=EXPENSES include=TABLE
ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -1031
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I can't tell from the above what privilege is missing, or if my command is telling `impdp` to do more than I'm expecting it to. I've tried skipping the `schemas` and `include` parameters with no difference.

Comment: Have you seen the MOS note **DataPump Import (`IMPDP`) Fails With Errors `ORA-1031 UDI-31626` If DBA Role Is Missing -- [ID 1459430.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1459430.1)**? Using a `DBA` user to perform the import (not necessarily `expenses1`) might solve the issue.

Comment: Don't have MOS access myself as a mere contractor (might have to see if I can) - but I'll try the DBA role, thanks.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: thanks. Tried it as SYSTEM and it worked.